# probability that specific bit is set

Tags: probability

Let $U_1,...,U_k$ be i.i.d uniform random variables over $\{0,1\}$. Let $W$ be an event that at least $n$ of these bits are set ($n<k$). What is $\Pr [U_j = 0 | W] $ for some $j\in [k]$?

I thought about looking over all possibilities for $n$ but no success. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bayes' theorem $$\text{Pr}[U_j = 0 \: | \: W] = \frac{\text{Pr}[U_j = 0]\text{Pr}[W \: | \: U_j = 0]}{\text{Pr}[W]}. \qquad \qquad (\star)$$
Now it's straightforward to see that $$\text{Pr}[U_j = 0] = \frac{1}{2}, \\ \text{Pr}[W \: | \: U_j = 0] = 2^{-(k - 1)}\sum_{i = n}^{k - 1} \binom{k - 1}{i} \quad \text{and} \\ \text{Pr}[W] = 2^{-k}\sum_{i = n}^k \binom{k}{i}$$ which, substiting in $(\star)$, give us $$\text{Pr}[U_j = 0 \: | \: W] = \frac{\sum_{i = n}^{k - 1} \binom{k - 1}{i}}{\sum_{i = n}^k \binom{k}{i}} = 1 - \left(\sum_{i = n}^k \binom{k}{i}\right)^{-1}.$$
I don't believe this can be simplified any further.

Answer (score 0):

Bits that are set?  If you don't specify, then they are still unknown, so that $Pr[U_j=0|W]=0.5$.